# Upsert Deadlock for non-trivial where clause

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I'm trying to write some SQL that does an upsert on a fairly complex criteria:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN;

  UPDATE LocationLog WITH(SERIALIZABLE)
  SET StartTime = CASE
      WHEN StartTime > @StartTime THEN @StartTime
      ELSE StartTime
    END,
    EndTime = CASE
      WHEN EndTime < @EndTime THEN @EndTime
      ELSE EndTime
    END,
    Updated = GETUTCDATE()
  WHERE Who = @Who
    AND (
        StartTime BETWEEN @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
        or
        EndTime BETWEEN @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
    )
    AND cast(Latitude as decimal(8,5)) = cast(@Latitude as decimal(8, 5))
    AND cast(Longitude as decimal(8,5)) = cast(@Longitude as decimal(8, 5))
    AND (Accuracy = @Accuracy or COALESCE(Accuracy, @Accuracy) is NULL)
    AND (Altitude = @Altitude or COALESCE(Altitude, @Altitude) is NULL)
    AND (AltitudeAccuracy = @AltitudeAccuracy or COALESCE(AltitudeAccuracy, @AltitudeAccuracy) is NULL)
    AND (Heading = @Heading or COALESCE(Heading, @Heading) is NULL)
    AND (Speed = @Speed or COALESCE(Speed, @Speed) is NULL);

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  BEGIN
    INSERT Position(UUID, Who, StartTime, EndTime, Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy, Altitude, AltitudeAccuracy, Heading, Speed, CreatedTime, Updated)
    VALUES (NEWID(), @Who, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Accuracy, @Altitude, @AltitudeAccuracy, @Heading, @Speed, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE())
  END

COMMIT TRAN
```

I'm using the standard "update, if @@rowcount = 0 insert" with a transaction and serializable, which is (near as I can tell) the same as [Sam Saffron's "Insert or Update pattern for Sql Server" Blog post](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx), except instead of using a single column ID, I'm using a large set of candidate columns, since there's no way to programmatically produce a single candidate key.

I'm getting deadlock when this is called concurrently, and I can't figure out why. Just to help complete the picture, here's the table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE LocationLog (
    [UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Position] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ,
    [Who] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL INDEX [IX_Who],
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Accuracy] [float] NULL,
    [Altitude] [float] NULL,
    [AltitudeAccuracy] [float] NULL,
    [Heading] [float] NULL,
    [Speed] [float] NULL,
    [CreatedUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

And here's a script that will cause a *lot* of deadlocks using the above sql: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xkze6l

I'm hoping for two things in an answer:

1. An explanation of why that deadlocks. (I've walked through the code, and I'm not understanding what I got wrong).
2. A fix for the code that will let me do this.

Comment: Any possibility of changing to a clustered IDENTITIY bigint primary key? Any way to eliminate the CAST()s in the WHERE clause, and provide appropriate indexes to facilitate that WHERE clause?

Comment: Post the deadlock graph - it tells you what is causing it.

Comment: And consider posting at https://dba.stackexchange.com as they specialise in database issues.

Comment: @pmbAustin I certainly plan on indexing this very carefully, and that may either a) include the CAST or b) swap the cast out for an indexed `PERSISTED` computed column...I"m aware of the performance issues here, but what I'm trying to figure out is the deadlock (which _may_ be related?). All that being said, I'm pretty positive the primary key is not at all part of the issue, especially since I explicitly marked it nonclustered to avoid fragmentation issues and since this is a standalone table with no other tables referring to it.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks! I'll do both (Deadlock graph, and consider dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to read [Conditional INSERT/UPDATE Race Condition](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2007/10/28/conditional-insertupdate-race-condition/) by Dan Guzman.

Most likely you need to add `HOLDLOCK` hint to your `UPDATE` statement. `HOLDLOCK` is needed to ensure that the lock is held until the end of the transaction.

As far I understand, your `WITH(SERIALIZABLE)` hint applies only to the `UPDATE` statement and doesn't affect the next `INSERT` statement.

This explains why you are getting deadlocks - the lock is held only for the duration of the `UPDATE` statement, then it is released, which allows another session to squeeze in, before the `INSERT`.

Maybe you'll need `UPDLOCK` as well, because even though it is an `UPDATE` statement, it has to find the rows to update first and the lock should be placed during this SELECT phase, before the UPDATE phase.

Answer (score 0):

This predicate:

```
AND (
    StartTime BETWEEN @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
    or
    EndTime BETWEEN @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
)
AND cast(Latitude as decimal(8,5)) = cast(@Latitude as decimal(8, 5))
AND cast(Longitude as decimal(8,5)) = cast(@Longitude as decimal(8, 5))
```

Will require a table scan.  So if you are going to scan the table every time, you might as well just use a TABLOCKX hint instead of SERIALIZABLE.